# How can I send some attributes to the callback function?

Tags: javascript

When I add an event listener like so: **oTarget.addEventListener(sEventType, fnHandler, false);** how can I send some attributes to the fnHandler function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can create an anonymous function that passes the additional parameters:

```
oTarget.addEventListener(sEventType, function(e) { 
    myFunction(e, attr2, attr3); 
}, false);
```

Comment: Anonymous functions work as long as you don't need to remove the listener at some point.

Comment: How would I then remove the listener that used an anonymous function as a callback function?

Comment: @Frank: unless you saved a reference to the anonymous function *somewhere*, you will not be able to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper function like:

```
oTarget.addEventListener(sEventType, function(evt) {
    return fnHandler(evt, "foo", "bar");
}, false)
```

Now you’re passing an anonymous function (the wrapper function) that calls `fnHandler` with the listed attributes and returns the value to where that callback function is called.

Comment: @meouw: It depends on what the caller does that calls the callback function.

Comment: but what happens in this particular case, the return isn't accessible is it? I always thought event handlers were void

Comment: @meouw: I'm with you. `return` is redundant here. It is ignored as per DOM spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener It's libraries like jQuery that make the `return` value of an event listener meaningful (as a convenience to `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`).